# Export CSV file to DataGridview in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using following code for exporting CSV file contents to DataGridView in C#. My Windows application is successfully running, but not display even Datagridview or anything in output.

I don't know where is the exact problem.

My aim is to display contents of .csv file in datagridview. I have stored the .csv file in my C drive, as specified in path.

```
Using System.data.Odbc;

namespace finaltry
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {


            string  ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=c:\;Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt";

            OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter("Select * FROM SharedIncidents.csv", conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "SharedIncidents");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager;
                conn.Close(); 

            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("error is" );



            }

        }
    }
}
```

My application is running successfully, but not showing anything in datagridview. Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try with this Sample Code,This works fine, i can be able to bind the csv content to Gridview control.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CSVSample.aspx.cs" Inherits="CSVSample" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv_csvupload">
    </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CodeBehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
public partial class CSVSample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + "E:\\FolderName\\" + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes'";
        //sample.csv is the csv which i used for my demo
        string CommandText = "select * from Sample.csv";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter(CommandText,conn);
        DataSet Sample=new DataSet();
        da.Fill(Sample);
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        gv_csvupload.DataSource = Sample;
        gv_csvupload.DataBind();                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramakrishnan mentioned in his sample... I think the only thing you are missing is the

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

clause... That basically pushes the data into the grid for display.